# Algorithm to find anagrams Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, nsdictionary, anagram

I've got an algorithm to find anagrams within a group of eight-letter words. Effectively it's alphabetizing the letters in the longer word, doing the same with the shorter words one by one, and seeing if they exist in the longer word, like so:

`tower = eortw`
`two = otw`
`rot = ort`

The issue here is that if I look for `ort` in `eortw` (or rot in tower), it'll find it, no problem. Rot is found inside tower. However, `otw` is not inside `eortw` (or two in tower), because of the R in the middle. Ergo, it doesn't think two is found in tower.

Is there a better way I can do this? I'm trying to do it in Objective-C, and both the eight-letter words and regular words are stored in `NSDictionaries` (with their normal and alphabetized forms).

I've looked at various other posts re. anagrams on StackOverflow, but none seem to address this particular issue.

Here's what I have so far:

```
- (BOOL) doesEightLetterWord: (NSString* )haystack containWord: (NSString *)needle {
    for (int i = 0; i < [needle length] + 1; i++) {
        if (!needle) {
            NSLog(@"DONE!");
        }

        NSString *currentCharacter = [needle substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
        NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: currentCharacter];
        NSLog(@"Current character is %@", currentCharacter);
        if ([haystack rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location == NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"The letter %@ isn't found in the word %@", currentCharacter,    haystack);
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"The letter %@ is found in the word %@", currentCharacter, haystack);
            int currentLocation = [haystack rangeOfCharacterFromSet: set].location;
            currentLocation++;    
            NSString *newHaystack = [haystack substringFromIndex: currentLocation];
            NSString *newNeedle = [needle substringFromIndex: i + 1];
            NSLog(@"newHaystack is %@", newHaystack);
            NSLog(@"newNeedle is %@", newNeedle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove all letters from the (ordered) haystack up to and including the first occurrence of the first character from the needle. Repeat until one or other of the words is empty?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand the needle/haystack analogy. Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: Apologies. I don't have time to give a concrete example until this evening, but the haystack is the word you're looking in (The longer word so say "eortw"), and the needle is the term you're looking for (You're actually only looking for the first letter each time, but say this is "otw" or "ort")

Comment: Okay, I think that makes sense, I can definitely have a try with it. If you do have more info later, I'd be very grateful, but thanks for this, it should work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one that approach I might take for finding out if one ordered word contained all of the letters of another ordered word. Note that it won't find true anagrams (That simply requires the two ordered strings to be the same) but this does what I think you're asking for:

```
+(BOOL) does: (NSString* )longWord contain: (NSString *)shortWord {
    NSString *haystack = [longWord copy];
    NSString *needle = [shortWord copy];
    while([haystack length] > 0 && [needle length] > 0) {
        NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: [needle substringToIndex:1]];
        if ([haystack rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location == NSNotFound) {
            return NO;
        }
        haystack = [haystack substringFromIndex: [haystack rangeOfCharacterFromSet: set].location+1];
        needle = [needle substringFromIndex: 1];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Looks good. Now to see whether stringAfterIndeex or getFirstIndex exist in any form in Objective-C..

Comment: @lukech I think you can use `substringFromIndex:` and `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:`

Comment: `substringFromIndex:` will work, but I need a way to get the first instance of that substring. I've revised to add the method so far above.

Comment: Also, are you returning a method call there?

Comment: It's a recursive approach, so it's saying "return the value of this function called with these parameters". I guess you could use a loop until one or other of the strings is empty.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do now, but I'm needing to use `[needle length]` to tell it how many times to iterate, which means that it finishes the loop with one character left in either list, and never gets so one of 'em is empty. Revised again, above.

Comment: Looks like this one has some bugs. It thinks `aaabrs` can be made from `aabeirsz` – I think the error is with there being three A's in there.

Comment: @lukech I've updated the answer with an actual Objective-c method that uses an iterative approach. I think the problem with the version in your question was that you were never updating `haystack` or `needle` - you were assigning the values to `newHaystack` and `newNeedle` (Which were convenience variables I used to try and make the recursion in my previous example cleaner)

Answer (score 1):

If you use only part of the letters it isn't a true anagram.

A good algorithm in your case would be to take the sorted strings and compare them letter by letter, skipping mis-matches in the longer word. If you reach the end of the shorter word then you have a match:

```
char *p1 = shorter_word;
char *p2 = longer_word;
int match = TRUE;
for (;*p1; p1++) {
  while (*p2 && (*p2 != *p1)) {
    p2++;
  }
  if (!*p2) {
    /* Letters of shorter word are not contained in longer word */
    match = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (but not most efficient) way might be to use `NSCountedSet`.  We can do this because for counted sets, `[a isSubsetOfSet:b]` return YES if and only if `[a countForObject:object] <= [b countForObject:object]` for every `object` in `a`.

Let's add a category to `NSString` to do it:

```
@interface NSString (lukech_superset)

- (BOOL)lukech_isSupersetOfString:(NSString *)needle;

@end

@implementation NSString (lukech_superset)

- (NSCountedSet *)lukech_countedSetOfCharacters {
    NSCountedSet *set = [NSCountedSet set];
    [self enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.length) options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
        [set addObject:substring];
    }];
    return set;
}

- (BOOL)lukech_isSupersetOfString:(NSString *)needle {
    return [[needle lukech_countedSetOfCharacters] isSubsetOfSet:[self lukech_countedSetOfCharacters]];
}

@end
```